# Use to_date as colum for cast function

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to achieve the following with Oracle database.

Current

```
table FTE
f_date    f_stime   f_eDate   f_etime  
20191125   14:00   20191125   14:01
```

Desired:

```
table FTE
f_date    f_stime   f_eDate   f_etime   f_Sdatetime        f_Edatetime
20191125   14:00   20191125   14:01      2019/11/25 14:00  2019/11/25 14:01
```

The date format is a number that needs the be converted to a date. I achieved this with the `to_date` function.

The time format is also a number.

Which function can I use to achieve this?

Comment: In the question it states: _The time format is also a number_. However, `14:00` and `14:01` are not numbers.  What is the actual format of those columns?

Comment: The data type of column `f_date` in database table `FTE` is NUMBER?

Comment: Yes to both questions,  i joined  dimension tables where the date and time is stored

Comment: @martin the format in the dimension table is nvarchar(8 char)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way, using `TO_DATE` along with string concatenation:

```
SELECT
    f_date,
    f_stime,
    f_eDate,
    f_etime,
    TO_DATE(f_date || f_stime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI') AS f_Sdatetime,
    TO_DATE(f_eDate || f_etime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI') AS f_Edatetime
FROM FTE;
```

### Demo

This assumes that you just want to form a datetime using the date and time components.  If you also want to *view* these datetimes in the exact format you showed us, then you would have to make an additional call to `TO_CHAR` with the appropriate mask:

```
SELECT
    f_date,
    f_stime,
    f_eDate,
    f_etime,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(f_date || f_stime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') AS f_Sdatetime,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(f_eDate || f_etime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') AS f_Edatetime
FROM FTE;
```

[image: screen capture of second query]

### Demo

Note that the *best* solution here would probably be to not store your date and time components separately, which would avoid the SQL acrobatics we are doing now.  Just use a single datetime/timestamp column instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The f_stime, is a joined column. 
The f_etime, is also a joined column. 
I joined time as f_stime and f_etime to make two sepearte columns

Can i use that "as" column that i defined in the to_date function?

Comment: @Henkiee20 No, you would either have to wrap your actual query, and then use the alias in the outer query, or just repeat the entire expression which generated your date.

Comment: Another advantage to using proper datatypes for date/time information is the Oracle optimizer can perform much better.  IE:  if your dates are stored as numbers, the optimizer thinks that are potentially 8,8690 values between `20191231` and `20200101` instead of zero values.  You could create a virtual column to avoid breaking existing code, and then just modify any queries using the date column.